# I am trying to stop a loop when user only clicks enter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to stop this loop when user enters a number <=0 or when user only cklicks enter.
how do i create the break when user only cklick enter?

```
    number = int(input('Type a number, [to stop type 0 or less]'))
    num_sum = number
    times = 0

    while True:
        number = int(input('Type a number, [to stop type 0 or less]'))
        num_sum += number
        times += 1
        if number <= 0:
            break

    average = num_sum / times
    print(f'{times} number received \nThe average of number recceived is:'+'{:.4f}'.format(average))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `input()` and `int()` as two separate steps.

```
while True:
    # call input() by itself, without calling int()
    answer = input('Type a number, [to stop type 0 or less]')

    # if the user pressed enter without typing an answer, break
    if not answer:
        break

    # otherwise convert answer to an integer
    number = int(answer)

    # remaining code is unchanged
```

Comment: Perhaps it is useful, to tell that an empty string - returned when only a enter is pressed - evaluates as False. upvoted anyway